# Use JavaScript to rename Google Spredsheet with current data

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

With this code it's possible rename document:

```js
function renomearArquivo() {
  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  s.rename("new file name");
}
```

How to do this function rename the file to "new filename 1/18"? Where 18 is the current day and 01 is January.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this one:

```
function renomearArquivo() {
  var today = new Date();
  var mm = today.getMonth()+1;
  var dd= today.getDate();
  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  s.rename("new filename " + mm + "/" + dd);
}
```